# Interface Builder wont let me rename the "View" class name to existing Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm following a tutorial from the book "Beginning iPhone Development", chapter 12.

I have a class called QuartzFunView with .h and .m files.

If I double click on my blaViewController.xib file, then click on "View" and in the Identity Inspector try to change the Class (Class identity) from UIView to QuartzFunView, my computer just beeps and stays as UIView. I can change the class to all the UI.. classes and any other random letter combination I choose, just not QuartzFunView. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simple question, but is `QuartzFunView` a subclass of UIView? (i.e., the declaration of the class reads `@interface QuartzFunView : UIView`?

You should post your code so we don't have to guess though.

Comment: Ahh, that solved it. You are a hero Bob, thank you!! I had read over the sample code in the tutorial so many times, don't know how i missed it

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this as answer because people do not need to read comment for answer

That existing class `QuartzFunView` must be a sub class of `UIView` class to be able to set as identifier of any `UIView` in xib file.